# Pronouncing "Scallywag"

Tags: pronunciation

I am old enough to have seen "Mischief Makers" (=Our Gang/Little Rascals,
mostly German version, but I also know the original: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXD6bvrE28E)).
Back then I of course didn't know what a scallywag is, let alone pronounce it.
Instinctively I say the first a is a German ä. Googling further, I found [this](https://www.facebook.com/LittleRascalsHistory/posts/skeedly-skeedly-theres-a-catchphrase-that-never-caught-on-around-this-time-in-19/130218354995524/?locale=de_DE).
In the Youtube vid, I still hear "Skillywag". And surely no bop (which allegedly
comes by default with skeedly) instead of wag. Note that the second reference even
includes a mention of scallawags(sic!), so I rather assume I heard correctly
and ä>short e>short i>long i is a dialect version.

Or am I the victim of an awfully sensible mondegreen?

Comment: I've always heard the word pronounced such that its vowels would rhyme with "alleyway."  The dictionary indicates multiple accepted pronunciations.  I guess one just gets to choose one.

Comment: People from New Zealand or South Africa would probably sound like they are saying 'skillywag'.

Comment: There are ***lots*** of Google Books matches for the spelling [***scallawag***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scallawag%22), so obviously at least *some* people reduce[d] the /i/ of the second syllable to a schwa. But *most* of us who still use the terml pronounce it with the "long" /i/.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've seen 'scalawag' in 19th century material.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yeah - I just put [d] after "reduce" to cover the possibility that most of the "less common" spellings might be older sources. But [here's the proof](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scallywag%2Cscallawag&year_start=1850&year_end=1950&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) that last century it was usually ***scallawag*** (underlined in red by my browser spell-checker! :) whereas today it's usually ***scallywag***.